Using reed switch for brake motor cutoff!
Changing mechanical disc brakes to Shimano MT200 hydraulic brakes without motor cutoff. Can I just use a reed switch and well placed magnet to work as motor cutoff on new to levers? The current Tektro mechanical levers have two pin connectors to controller.

Grin sells something a little like you describe, or did. Also I haven't done this firsthand so I'm not posting it as an answer, but: Magura makes an inline switch activated by hydraulic pressure that's a 2-wire, normally open type, and you can just buy it. I understand that some shops are using it as a semi-generic cutoff switch. You'll have to work out for yourself the hose/fitting part, since it expects Magura parts but you'll have Shimano lines coming off your lever.

Thanks for your response.  I checked the price of the hydraulic sensor and at $45 each and the complexity of the tubing adaption they don't appeal to me as a solution. I found brake sensors with the correct (red) two pin connectors for my ebike (Blix Vika+) so will try those.
